# The flutter SDK is incomplete

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

When I try to create a new application in android studio, it asks for the SDK. When I give the SDK, it shows "the flutter SDK installation is incomplete". Please help me out with this. I've attached the screenshot. Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Paste your `flutter doctor` output

Comment: Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1256], locale en-IN)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

Comment: Installing a new Sdk via zip file, i had the same problem, but running `flutter doctor` the installation completed successfully and the error in AS disappeared (maybe after restarting it).

Comment: It worked after restarting! thanks a lot

Comment: In my case, I'd first installed the flutter plugin in Android studio, then installed flutter with brew, and *then* installed the SDK.  Running `flutter doctor` was obvs using brew.  I needed to run `<SDK_PATH>/bin/flutter doctor`, which then did some stuff like download dart and build some stuff.  Once I'd done that, Android studio was happy to use the <SDK_PATH> as input for that dialog.

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to flutter extracted location
2. flutter/bin
3. open CMD window here
4. run flutter doctor
   This will install remaining libraries and then give path to your android studio IDE
   [EXAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIbFK.png)

Comment: I traced your mention, but, unfortunately, after I wrote flutter doctor and pressed enter button, with some lines like your image at the top, it has crash and has close automatically. All in all, I could not install based on your approach.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I didn't found any solution even on stackoverflow.
what I did was I just removed the sdk and its path variable and downloaded the new version of sdk. worked for me C:\src\flutter\flutter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download "flutter_windows_1.22.6-stable.zip" from https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/windows/flutter_windows_1.22.6-stable.zip.
2. Extract files.
3. Turn on a VPN (ex: Hotspot Shield).
4. Click right-click on "Extracted files: flutter\bin\dart.bat > Run as administrator.
5. Wait for downloading.
6. Go to edit variables (This PC > properties > Advanced system settings > Advanced > Environment Variables).
7. Edit (create if not exist) Path variable to "Extracted files: flutter\bin" then click ok.
8. Download and install Git from https://git-scm.com/download/win.
9. Open cmd, write "flutter", wait to download.
10. Write "flutter doctor" in cmd, and solve all the problems they pose.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for windows. You need this steps:

1.Run cmd(as administrator) and command cd in to your flutter directory(not flutter/bin )

2.Run flutter doctor in console. you may have to wait a while - this will download dependencies.